# Null Pointer creating Contact in Android SQL

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I had a LinkedList to save my points, but know I want to use an sqlite database instead.

This is my point class, I will just list the variables. All of them have getters and setters.

```
public Point(String Serial, String Observation, boolean tir, double x, double y, int networkNumber, int potencia,
                 int ColumnNr, int Column, int lamp, int armor, int lampState) {
        this.Serial = Serial;
        this.Observations = Observation;
        this.tir = tir;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.networkNumber = networkNumber;
        this.potencia = potencia;
        this.ColumnNr = ColumnNr;
        this.Column = Column;
        this.lamp = lamp;
        this.armor = armor;
        this.lampState = lampState;
    }
```

This is my PointsDB classe

```
public class PointsDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String ID = "_id";
    public static final String SERIAL = "Serial";
    public static final String OBSERVATIONS = "Observações";
    public static final String TIR = "tir";
    public static final String X = "X";
    public static final String Y = "Y";
    public static final String NETWORKNUMBER = "Rede";
    public static final String POTENCIA = "Potencia";
    public static final String COLUMNNR = "Numero Coluna";
    public static final String COLUMN = "Coluna";
    public static final String LAMP = "Lampada";
    public static final String ARMOR = "Armadura";
    public static final String LAMPSTATE = "Estado da Lampada";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pontos.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "pontos";
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_NAME + "( " + ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + SERIAL
            + " text not null, " + OBSERVATIONS + " text not null, "
            + TIR + " text not null" +
            ", " + X + " text not null " + Y + " text not null, " + NETWORKNUMBER + " text not null, " + POTENCIA + " text not null, "
            + COLUMNNR + " text not null, " + COLUMN + " text not null, " + LAMP + " text not null, "
            + ARMOR + " text not null, " + LAMPSTATE + " text not null);";

    public PointsDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(PointsDB.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data"
        );
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

And this is my PointsDBAdapter

```
public class PointsDBAdapter {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private PointsDB points;
    private String[] allColumns = {PointsDB.ID, PointsDB.SERIAL, PointsDB.OBSERVATIONS, PointsDB.TIR, PointsDB.X, PointsDB.Y,
    PointsDB.NETWORKNUMBER, PointsDB.POTENCIA, PointsDB.COLUMNNR, PointsDB.COLUMN, PointsDB.LAMP, PointsDB.ARMOR, PointsDB.LAMPSTATE};

    public PointsDBAdapter(Context context) {
        points = new PointsDB(context);
    }

    public Point createContacto(String Serial, String Observation, boolean tir, double x, double y, int networkNumber, int potencia,
                                int ColumnNr, int Column, int lamp, int armor, int lampState) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(PointsDB.SERIAL, Serial);
        Log.d("1", Serial);
        values.put(PointsDB.OBSERVATIONS, Observation);
        Log.d("2", Observation);
        values.put(PointsDB.TIR,tir);
        Log.d("3", "tir" + tir);
        values.put(PointsDB.X, x);
        Log.d("4","x" + x);
        values.put(PointsDB.Y, y);
        values.put(PointsDB.NETWORKNUMBER, networkNumber);
        values.put(PointsDB.POTENCIA, potencia);
        values.put(PointsDB.COLUMNNR, ColumnNr);
        values.put(PointsDB.COLUMN, Column);
        values.put(PointsDB.LAMP, lamp);
        values.put(PointsDB.ARMOR, armor);
        values.put(PointsDB.LAMPSTATE, lampState);
        long insertId = database.insert(PointsDB.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        // To show how to query
        Cursor cursor = database.query(PointsDB.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, PointsDB.ID + " = " +
                insertId, null,null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursorToPoint(cursor);
    }

    private Point cursorToPoint(Cursor cursor) {
        Point point = new
                Point(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), Boolean.parseBoolean(cursor.getString(2)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)),
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)),
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(9)),
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(10)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(11)));
        return point;
    }

    public void deletePoint(int idPoint){
        database.delete(PointsDB.TABLE_NAME, PointsDB.ID + " = " + idPoint,
                null);
    }

    public Cursor getContactos(){
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select _id, Serial,Observações,tir, X, Y, Rede, Potencia, Numero Coluna, Coluna," +
                        "Lampada, Armadura, Estado de Lampada from pontos", null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public Point getPoint(int idPoint){
        Cursor cursor = database.query(PointsDB.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, PointsDB.ID + " = " +
                idPoint, null,null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursorToPoint(cursor);
    }

    public int getSize() {
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + PointsDB.TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
        return (int) statement.simpleQueryForLong();
    }

    public long count() {
        return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(database,PointsDB.TABLE_NAME);
    }
}
```

Finally, I've a CreatePoint Class which inside my CreateView has:

```
      final EditText SerialField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Serial);
        final EditText ObservationField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Observation);
        final EditText XField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.XField);
        final EditText YField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.YField);
        final EditText columnNrField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ColumnNr);
        final EditText intensityField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Intensity);
        final CheckBox status = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
        final Spinner networkSpinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        final Spinner columnSpinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        final Spinner lampSpinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        final Spinner armorSpinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner4);

 Button buttonGuardar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonGuardar);
            buttonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String Serial = SerialField.getText().toString();
                    String Observation = ObservationField.getText().toString();
                    double X = Double.parseDouble(XField.getText().toString());
                    double Y = Double.parseDouble(YField.getText().toString());
                    int columnNumber = Integer.parseInt(columnNrField.getText().toString());
                    int intensity = Integer.parseInt(intensityField.getText().toString());
                    int networkToSet = networkSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    boolean checkBoxStatus = status.isChecked();
                    int valToSet = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    int setColumn = columnSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    int setLamp = lampSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    int setArmor = armorSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

pointsList.createContacto(Serial, Observation, checkBoxStatus, X, Y, networkToSet, columnNumber, intensity, setColumn, setLamp, setArmor, valToSet);

                    Fragment fragment = new PointsList();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                            .commit();
                }
            });
```

But when I'm trying to create a point it doesn't work.

My logcat error points to:

```
long insertId = database.insert(PointsDB.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Here is it by the way:

```
04-15 15:51:56.950  16194-16194/com.example.testlayout.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 186K, 3% free 8172K/8396K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
04-15 15:52:02.880  16194-16194/com.example.testlayout.app D/1﹕ oi
04-15 15:52:02.880  16194-16194/com.example.testlayout.app D/2﹕ hhh
04-15 15:52:02.880  16194-16194/com.example.testlayout.app D/3﹕ tirtrue
04-15 15:52:02.880  16194-16194/com.example.testlayout.app D/4﹕ x555.0
04-15 15:52:02.880  16194-16194/com.example.testlayout.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-15 15:52:02.880  16194-16194/com.example.testlayout.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418a1ba8)
04-15 15:52:02.880  16194-16194/com.example.testlayout.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testlayout.app, PID: 16194
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.testlayout.app.PointsDBAdapter.createContacto(PointsDBAdapter.java:44)
            at com.example.testlayout.app.CreatePoint$1.onClick(CreatePoint.java:86)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You changed your question, put in the hints that we gave you, and then after it solved your NullPointerException asked for the next error that you got. That's not good practice, because it makes the first answers useless.

Comment: already flagged it!

sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to initialize `database` variable before calling:

```
long insertId = database.insert(PointsDB.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

You should do:

```
database = points.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: how do I initialize it? My DBHelper is PointsDB, am I missing any method there?

Answer (score 0):

Your `database` object is null. Make sure it's initialized.

Probably you forgot to give your `PointsDBAdapter` class the `open()` method (and to call it):

```
public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = points.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Comment: where do I call it? in my DbAdapter, in my DBhelper or in my PointsList?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a coma:

```
X text not null Y text not null
```

between the declaration of X and Y. This is exactly why it is not a good idea to write all the SQL yourself for creating the table, querying the base...

Using a library such as GreenDAO or ORMlite does make things simpler. Even writing your own library is not very complicated and will result in lesser probability of typos. (I never write SQL. I wrote a basic library once, I extend it from times to times, and have used it since.)

Also, you need to learn to read the error message. This one is pretty explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Your log cat points to an SQL Syntax Error.So for solving just change this line.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_NAME + "( " + ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + SERIAL
            + " text not null, " + OBSERVATIONS + " text not null, "
            + TIR + " text not null" +
            ", " + X + " text not null " + Y + " text not null, " + NETWORKNUMBER + " text not null, " + POTENCIA + " text not null, "
            + COLUMNNR + " text not null, " + COLUMN + " text not null, " + LAMP + " text not null, "
            + ARMOR + " text not null, " + LAMPSTATE + " text not null);";
```

**WITH THIS**

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_NAME + "( " + ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + SERIAL
        + " text not null, " + OBSERVATIONS + " text not null, "
        + TIR + " text not null" +
        ", " + X + " text not null, " + Y + " text not null, " + NETWORKNUMBER + " text not null, " + POTENCIA + " text not null, "
        + COLUMNNR + " text not null, " + COLUMN + " text not null, " + LAMP + " text not null, "
        + ARMOR + " text not null, " + LAMPSTATE + " text not null);";
```